# C#.net Getting values from json

Tags: c#, json, socket.io

I need to use some JSON data with a C# application, but i can't figure a way of getting the data.
I'm using SOCKET.IO, and here is a sample of a raw json string that is recieved

```
`socket.On("recieved", (data) =>
{
    MessageBox.Show(data.Json.ToJsonString());
    //outputs :  {'name':'received','args':[{'data':'somedata'}]}
    //get values from data
}`<br>
```

and i need to retrieve the value of 'data'

Comment: Use [JavaScriptSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: What does your message box show?  Are you getting any errors?

Comment: https://www.nuget.org/packages/newtonsoft.json/

Answer (score 0):

Look at the examples in the SocketIO4Net archive.
Define a class

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace TestProject
{
    [JsonObject(MemberSerialization.OptIn)]
    public class JSonData
    {
        [JsonProperty]
        public string data { get; set; }

        public JSonData()
        {
        }

        public string ToJsonString()
        {
            return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this);
        }
        public static JSonData Deserialize(string jsonString)
        {
            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JSonData>(jsonString);
        }
    }
}
```

And after you get data like this :

```
JSonData JData = data.Json.GetFirstArgAs<JSonData>();
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok i got that working, but if i want all args in JSON string `{data:"somedata",anotherdata:'someanotherdata'}` and get 'anotherdata', i tried 
`
JSonData part = data.Json.GetArgsAs();

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the double answers, but this did it for me 
`private Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject get_data(SocketIOClient.Messages.JsonEncodedEventMessage data)
        {
            var inputdata = data;
            dynamic jsondata =  inputdata.GetArgsAs<Object>();
            jsondata = jsondata[0];
            return jsondata;
        }`

and then just do  
`dynamic json = get_data(data.Json);`